# How to allow edit within/from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Scenario: I have an application where my java application pushes user data from database to Elastic search which is accessed using Kibana dashboards. I also have a Content application which allow users to create/edit data which is saved in database using my java application.

Use case: When user slices data in Kibana dashboards and reaches a point where he realize an error in data, he would want to make change to the data point. E.g. certain company is shown in a particular city in the dashboard which seems to be an incorrect data. User would want to change the city to the correct one.

Problem case: I am not able find a way to either allow the data to be edited within Kibana or have some kind of deeplink in Kibana which takes user from Kibana to my Content application so that the data point can be edited by user.
Currently the user can go to the Content application, search for the company, search for the addresses and make a change there, however thats very cumbersome to do with millions of companies and millions of data points in database.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found editing possibilities up to now ... but linking is possible: 
when you head to "Kibana/Mgmt/Index Patterns" you can define fields to render as a clickable URL (e.g. to be used in the "Data Table" vis).
If you have a field containing e.g. some ID `myid` you can have kibana output a clickable link instead pointing to e.g. `https://mysite/?id=myid`
See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/field-formatters-string.html for details.

If you need more complex linking options (e.g. your effective link needs to incorporate multiple fields of a document) you can create a so called scripted field, there you have access to multiple fields of an elasticsearch document and can construct your link more or less freely).
We use that a lot to link from overview kibana dashboards to other systems with detailed data on the respective item, see for example this Data Table:
[image]

Comment: this sounds very elegant.